# Extending embedded python in c++ - PyMethodDef issue

Tags: python, c++

Trying to extend embedded python in C++. In this case one method definition in "PyMethodDef" function works fine. I case more method definition works only the first one. Here is an example:

```
static char *y = new char[100];
/* Return the number of arguments of the application command line */
static PyObject* hashlib_sha256(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"y", &y))
       return NULL;
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 1);
}
static PyObject* hashlib_hexdigest(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ""))
       return NULL;
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 0);
}
static PyMethodDef HahlibMethods[] = {
     {"sha256", hashlib_sha256, METH_VARARGS, ""},
     {"hexdigest", hashlib_hexdigest, METH_VARARGS, ""},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
}
static PyModuleDef HashlibModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "hashlib", NULL, -1, HahlibMethods,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
}
static PyObject* PyInit_hashlib(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&HashlibModule);
}
```

and in the main I use the following method before the `Py_Initialize()` call

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("hashlib", &PyInit_hashlib);
```

Python code:

```
import hashlib

def getILoomaAddress():
    sha_256 = hashlib.sha256(b'Hello World!')
    result = sha_256.hexdigest()
    return result
```

So the first `sha256` method works fine but the `hexdigest` does not.
What is the problem here, why the `hashlib_hexdigest` is not called?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is there an error?  Is it returning a value you don't expect?

Comment: When I try to debug it the process stops and alert window appears in visual studio with the "Unhandled exception at 0x00D8FCFF in qt.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004." message. if I comment the "sha_256.hexdigest()" call inside the python file works fine.